# IE unable to download CSV files from SharePoint 2010 document library

Tags: internet-explorer, csv, sharepoint-2010, download

I developed a web app in SP2010. The entire app is done in JavaScript with SPServices, since the customer (the Marine Corp.) doesn't want to allow any .NET development in their environment. The customer wanted to be able to download all of the reports in Excel spreadsheets so they can do whatever they do with them. Since it's impossible to generate Excel spreadsheets in JavaScript, the workaround I came up with was to generate a CSV in JavaScript, and save it to a document library, then point the browser to the CSV file for download. This worked perfectly. Even though it wasn't technically Excel, the customer didn't know any better. It just provided what they asked for: open the report in Excel. But the other day, the customer said the Export stopped working. I've spent about a day and a half trying to see what's wrong, find a solution, all that jazz. Here's what I've noticed:

- The ".csv" extension is being changed by the browser to "_csv"
- When you click "Save" in the download dialog, the browser reports "[filename]_csv couldn't be downloaded [Retry] [Cancel]"
- When looking at the response headers from the SP server using a protocol analyzer, the SP server is giving the browser the correct file name in the content disposition
- The problem exists in all versions of IE, but works fine in FF. No testing done for Chrome/Safari

Here's the HTTP response headers from the SP2010 server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control   private,max-age=0
Content-Length  27739
Content-Type    application/octet-stream
Expires Sun, 28 Jul 2013 13:42:43 GMT
Last-Modified   Mon, 12 Aug 2013 13:42:43 GMT
ETag    "{AE0131B1-3C1D-4E24-BB97-D4D0EB8C69F2},20"
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid   903d68dc-6f49-4fd8-acbc-2b22c4ee28ef
Set-Cookie  WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={cbef9658-700b-421b-87d5-08fbdc520faf}; path=/
X-SharePointHealthScore 0
ResourceTag rt:AE0131B1-3C1D-4E24-BB97-D4D0EB8C69F2@00000000020
X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
Content-Disposition attachment; filename=test.csv
X-Download-Options  noopen
Public-Extension    http://schemas.microsoft.com/repl-2
Set-Cookie  WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={cbef9658-700b-421b-87d5-08fbdc520faf}; path=/
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices 14.0.0.6029
Date    Mon, 12 Aug 2013 13:42:42 GMT
```

Since IE seems to be the only browser affected, I'm unsure if the issue is with the server response. But then again, I come from a LAMP development background, so some of these headers are foreign to me. I was hoping someone out there in Internet-land would have some idea of what's going on here, or have **something** that will give me even a little clue as to what might have changed (apparently overnight) or what the problem could be.

Here's a full fiddler capture, with the URL and filename removed for security, as well as the file contents. I **had** to remove these items because it's a Marine Corp. application and data.

```
GET http://removed_for_security/Reports/filename.csv HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MDDC; InfoPath    .3)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: sp2010dev
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={cbef9658-700b-421b-87d5-08fbdc520faf}


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private,max-age=0
Content-Length: 27739
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Expires: Sun, 28 Jul 2013 19:48:33 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 12 Aug 2013 19:48:33 GMT
ETag: "{AE0131B1-3C1D-4E24-BB97-D4D0EB8C69F2},30"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: a39fa60c-5b8c-4b8c-bb8c-bc1f72ab0351
Set-Cookie: WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={cbef9658-700b-421b-87d5-08fbdc520faf}; path=/
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
ResourceTag: rt:AE0131B1-3C1D-4E24-BB97-D4D0EB8C69F2@00000000030
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.csv
X-Download-Options: noopen
Public-Extension: http://schemas.microsoft.com/repl-2
Set-Cookie: WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={cbef9658-700b-421b-87d5-08fbdc520faf}; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.6029
Date: Mon, 12 Aug 2013 19:48:32 GMT

file_contents
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE are you hitting this with? How exactly are you generating the CSV file?

The problem sounds like this one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/07/16/content-length-and-transfer-encoding-validation-in-ie10-download-manager-couldnt-be-downloaded-retry-cancel.aspx

You might also changing the Content-Type to the proper one ("text/csv") to eliminate the possibility of MIME-sniffing.

Can you collect and share a Fiddler capture of the failing scenario?

Comment: I used IE 7 (both with and without compatibility mode), IE 9, and IE 10. All are affected.

Comment: Well, 2 things: 1) Changing the MIME type will require a configuration change on the server side of things, which we're not allowed to do. 2) I see at least one response header that directs the browser not to do MIME sniffing.

Comment: The whole reason we built this app in JS/SPServices is because we basically get an out-of-the-box install of SP2010 to work with, with **NO** custom configuration or .NET code allowed.

Comment: Noniff is only meaningful for IE8+. Have you managed to repro this on a client PC that does NOT have Excel installed? You'd see a problem like this if the MIME Handler that Excel registers is broken...

Comment: Oh, yeah, how am I generating the CSV. I have a function that if you pass an array of objects, it returns a string, whose value is essentially a CSV file contents. The objects are in the format `{column1:value1, column2:value2...}` Since it's hard to get from string variable in JS to downloadable file, I have to send the string contents to document library using AJAX call to SP web services, and then call window.open(pathToCSVFileInDocLib).  
  
We didn't test downloading the CSVs on a machine that doesn't have Excel installed.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently there's a problem with IE security (surprise) preventing the download. I worked around it by going to `Internet Options > Security > Local Intranet > Sites > Advanced` and adding the domain that hosts the SP site. And to fix the issue with IE changing ".csv" to "_csv" I changed the MIME type for that extension in IIS manager. So now everything works as it should